# How to change validation message only for Regex pattern during email validation

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation

Iam using html5 validation for email ..But there it is not validating for .com or .co.So Iam using regex for that

```
[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$
```

If i dont give @ it is giving html5 validation message which is fine..But if we dont give . and following com it is giving regex message as "Please match the requested format"..How can we change this message to a meaningful one.But the other messages shouldnt be changed.

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$" required/>
```

Thanks

Jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/T29Kx/369/

Comment: I know this is not what you asked, but you really shouldn't try to validate someone's email -> https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Answer (score 3):

It's not supported on every browser (i think safari lacks support for it) but you can use the oninvalid and setCustomValidity methods

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Plz enter valid email')" required/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: But it keeps blinking the validation msg even the correct one is given..how to stop that?

Comment: Actually, that is a standard, even if weird, behaviour of chrome. even without the oninvalid handler it does the same. You can use setCustomValidity('') to reset the custom message tho

Comment: But on using onvalid validation message,Iam lossing the default validation messages which we get for email required for html5